# Cannot resolve symbol v7 and appComapat Activity imports in android studio

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am stuck on this problem for 3-4 days and I have tried everything within my reach, cleared caches, cleaned the project and still it doesnt run on a device. The error pops up displaying cannot resolve v7.app.appcompatActivity. Thanks for the help, the code is below:
package com.edunomics.flashchatnewfirebase;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppcompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class MainChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // TODO: Add member variables here:
    private String mDisplayName;
    private ListView mChatListView;
    private EditText mInputText;
    private ImageButton mSendButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_chat);

        // TODO: Set up the display name and get the Firebase reference


        // Link the Views in the layout to the Java code
        mInputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageInput);
        mSendButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
        mChatListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.chat_list_view);

        // TODO: Send the message when the "enter" button is pressed


        // TODO: Add an OnClickListener to the sendButton to send a message

    }

    // TODO: Retrieve the display name from the Shared Preferences


    private void sendMessage() {

        // TODO: Grab the text the user typed in and push the message to Firebase

    }

    // TODO: Override the onStart() lifecycle method. Setup the adapter here.


    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // TODO: Remove the Firebase event listener on the adapter.

    }

}
```

This is my build.gradle file for app

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Please share your app gradle file

Answer (score 0):

Only one `import` statement is needed. Please replace the following `import` statement

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

with below `import` statement.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

Comment: I have already added that , check above, still its showing cannot resolve appcompat Activity

Comment: Yes. you need to remove `import android.support.v7.app.AppcompatActivity;`

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 issues:

1. You cannot have two import statements that import different classes with the same name;
2. You do not have dependencies to resolve `android.support.v7` package.

Remove this import:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```